# SPSS keyboard combination alters encoding

Tags: spss

My question does not have to do with programming but with a practical issue on SPSS. By accident a keyword combination that I cannot remember because I did not intend to press changed the encoding in SPSS and the text in the data that were in different language than english is shown as small boxes. Nevertheless, when some kind of analysis is performed the different language text is shown properly in the output.

Does anybody know the reason? I tried to change the encoding but it did not produce any result.

Answer (score 0):

First, look at Edit > Options and see whether the setting is Unicode or locale.  That might fix it.  If you have text in multiple languages, you probably want Unicode.  Otherwise, you may have the specific locale set wrong.  You can change it with
SET LOCALE, but you need to know which locale you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The other possibility is that you have managed to change the user interface font.  See if your preference setting for Look and Feel is SPSS Standard.